# Put overlay on document with transparent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to do something with my document which is quite unique (haven't seen it before) and thus maybe not even possible.

What I would like is to have a div which will overlay everything in the document, maybe give it background black so that nothing is visible. Second I would like to have a small squire window in the overlay which doesn't share the black background, in fact it is somewhat transparent and therefore it would be possible to 'peek' trough that window to see document content. But only the content where this window is. It would be kinda like those "zoom" plugins in which only a small portion is being zoomed, but in this case it would show specific content. Any idea how to create such a thing?

Comment: Sounds like a movable lightbox - so will you move the box or the content under it?

Comment: @mplungjan I would move the box (but position is predefined, so no actual moving). But I think lightbox is different as it holds the content itself.

Comment: [This could be start of a very rough draft](http://jsfiddle.net/nSTvC/)

Comment: @mplungjan What do you mean by "top div"? If you mean the "overlay div" that one should be black

Comment: @Ohgodwhy really nice.

Comment: @mplungjan In that case; the overlay (not the content) will show trough

Comment: Yes, I realise that now I tried :) @Ohgodwhy should post as answer

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/4SygN/1/) may also be something

Comment: @mplungjan I don't like posting things as answers when they're psuedo and I haven't really given them much thought. People coming from the future might be mislead.

Comment: @Spokey Incredible, thank you very much(: I will accept if you post as answer (exactly what I was looking for)

Comment: I will post just to explain how it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example of what you can do is the following (it may not be the best but it works)

**HTML**

```
<div id='peakview'></div> <!-- This div is your view window -->
<div id='out'>
    <div class='overlay'></div>
    <div class='overlay'></div>
    <div class='overlay'></div>
    <div class='overlay'></div>
</div>
```

The `<div>` inside of `#out` will re-size accordingly to the position of `#peakview` creating the illusion of a full overlay. This can be done with simple `css` and some calculus.

Mainly what you need is the position of the element on screen.

```
var h = $(this).offset().top;
var l = $(this).offset().left;
var r = ($(window).width() - ($(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth()));
//right offset
var b = ($(window).height() - ($(this).offset().top + $(this).outerWidth()));
//bottom offset
```

In my example I used `.draggable()` from `jQuery UI` to move the div around. And while dragging the 4 `div`s shown above are adjusting their height and width to fill up the space between `#peakview` and `document border`.

**An example for the first div**

```
$('.overlay:eq(0)').css({
     top: 0,
     left: 0,
     width: '100%',
     height: h  //the height is always changing depending on the #peakview .offset().top
});
```

[In this fiddle you will see how the filling `div`s behave](http://jsfiddle.net/4SygN/3/)

Comment: Thank you very much, also for explaing in such detail and providing the second example. I think this is all I need:)

Answer (score 2):

Another ruff start:

http://jsfiddle.net/XDrSA/

This require some extra work, but it may suit your needs.

HTML:

```
<div id="yourContent" style="width: 300px; margin:100px auto;">
    <input type="button" id="zoom" value="Click to zoom"/>
</div>

<div id="zoomer">
    <div id="window">This is your "window"</div>
    <div id="overlay_top"></div>
    <div id="overlay_left"></div>
    <div id="overlay_right"></div>
    <div id="overlay_bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#zoomer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}
#overlay_top {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0
}

#overlay_right {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: black;    
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

#overlay_left {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: black;    
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

#overlay_bottom {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;    
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

#window {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

And a piece of javascript:

```
$('#zoom').click(function() {
   $('#zoomer').fadeIn();
});
```

You may need to stumble with the positioning, and the window will be a fixed size one. Not draggable though.

Comment: Thanks:) will accept (as it is a start) if nothing else comes along